# Microsoft cognitive services - Client Library. Error "A procedure imported by 'SpeechClient.dll' could not be loaded."

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am exploring Microsoft cognitive services. I download the speech API client library through SDK (https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-speech-stt-windows). I want to convert audio file (.wav) to text. But while trying to run this application it give error message as

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: A procedure imported by 'SpeechClient.dll' could not be loaded."

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7ULl.jpg)

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Bishwa

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the issue is Windows 7. T am also running into the same issue and have found a couple of references that “The Windows Speech library has a hard dependency on the Windows 8 network stack”.

Cheers
Michael